# combineEpics using TypeScript gives type error

Tags: typescript, rxjs, redux-observable

I am getting this error when combining my epics:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Epic<SessionAction, GlobalState, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Epic<EmployeeAction, GlobalState, any>'.
Type 'SessionAction' is not assignable to type 'EmployeeAction'.
Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
  Type 'SessionActionTypes' is not assignable to type 'EmployeeActionTypes'.
```

The following is the code:

```
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { fetchUserSession } from './sessionEpics';
import { fetchEmployee } from './employeeEpics';

export default combineEpics(
  fetchEmployee,
  fetchUserSession
);
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have pretty much the same problem. It seems like typescript grabs the first epic, infers it's type and expect all the rest to be the same.

What I did was cast the first one.

Using your code as example:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { fetchUserSession } from './sessionEpics';
import { fetchEmployee } from './employeeEpics';

export default combineEpics(
  fetchEmployee as Observable<AnyAction>,
  fetchUserSession
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use `combineEpics<any>`:

```
export default combineEpics<any>(
  fetchEmployee,
  fetchUserSession
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution might be using the correct types: `AnyAction` and `Observable`:

```js
import { AnyAction } from "redux"
import { combineEpics, createEpicMiddleware } from "redux-observable"
import { Observable } from "rxjs"

export const clientMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(
  combineEpics<AnyAction, Observable<AnyAction>>(
    authenticateEpic(request),
    registerEpic(request)
  ))
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain why these are the correct types? what's the logic behind this?